# How to bind data like gridview using listbox in windows phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

In my app i want to bind data like gridview.Since there is no gridview for windows phone and 
listbox shows data vertically .How to achieve this.
Here is my code

```
<ListBox x:Name="listbox">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="200" Height="200" Background="Blue"/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

How to show template like windows 8 start screen.?

Comment: Not sure I understand but there is [`GridView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.gridview.aspx) control for Windows Phone which _displays a horizontal grid of data items_

Comment: @dkozi, there is no GridView control in Windows Phone SDK. There is for Windows 8.

Comment: How to achieve that any ways for that ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it this way..

```
<listbox itemssource="{Binding MyList}" scrollviewer.horizontalscrollbarvisibility="Auto" scrollviewer.verticalscrollbarvisibility="Disabled">
<listbox.itemspanel>
    <itemspaneltemplate>
        <!-- Could be a VirtualizingStackPanel if you wish -->
        <stackpanel orientation="Horizontal">
    </stackpanel></itemspaneltemplate>
</listbox.itemspanel>
<listbox.itemtemplate>
    <datatemplate>
        <!-- Style set to enhance need for scrolling -->
        <textblock style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" text="{Binding}">
    </textblock></datatemplate>
</listbox.itemtemplate>
```